# Is it correct to say "Yesterday night"?

Tags: grammaticality, colloquialisms, time, compounds

I have heard a lot of people say "Yesterday night" is that considered correct? I have always said *last night*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange, as noted in the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help), is that questions indicate initial research attempts and provide context. In what part of the world are these people located? What do your web searches turn up? Why do you consider it to be *incorrect* instead of merely different?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you hear this? It is not standard or idiomatic English, and sounds quite odd to this native speaker. It sounds like a direct translation of a non-English term.

The correct way to say this is as you suggest the more concise "last night."

Comment: And yet I'd feel more comfortable with the phrase "yesterday evening" than "last evening".

Comment: "Yesterday night" is standard usage in British English.

Comment: @AE ‘Standard usage’? Do you have anything to corroborate that? I certainly don’t recall ever hearing anyone say it in BrE, and [this Ngram](http://bit.ly/1z1b1ER) shows _last night_ being somewhere around **eight thousand** times more common than _yesterday night_, which is hardly what you’d expect of something that was standard usage.

Comment: @Janus, [Dickens](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=puJqxFvgoX8C&lpg=PA45&dq=%22yesterday%20night%22&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q=%22yesterday%20night%22&f=false), [Thackeray](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_bbFjKAxljoC&lpg=PA112&dq=%22yesterday%20night%22&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=%22yesterday%20night%22&f=false), [Austen](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n1sbAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT83&dq=%22yesterday%20night%22%20jane%20austen&pg=PT83#v=onepage&q=%22yesterday%20night%22&f=false), [17,000 more](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22yesterday+night%22&tbm=bks&start=10)

Comment: It's not synonymous with 'last night'. 'Last night' is the dark period between yesterday and today, whereas 'yesterday night' is the evening of yesterday.

Comment: @AE Well, Dickens and Thackeray aren't really indicative of it being standard in current English. I'm not saying it doesn't exist, but calling it _standard_ seems an exaggeration to me; compare those 17,000 hits to the 10,7 **million** hits for ‘last night’. Not quite the 1:8000 ratio from the Ngram, but still more than 1:600.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, as I said, the meaning is different. ['Yesterday night' versus 'yesterday evening'] is a fairer comparison. There are a lot less results for 'yesterday night' - it may be regional variation?

Comment: @AE I didn't see your previous comment; but I don't recognise this distinction you mention, either. _Last night_ generally means either thing in my experience. There's nothing uncommon about “We went out for dinner last night”, for example, even if it was high summer and you were back home by 8 PM.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, true. OK, 'last night' can be yesterday evening or it can be the sleepy period following.